# Replacing a specific string in a file using regex PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

I'm tagging a file using Stanford NER and I want to replace every "O" tag with "NONE". I've already tried this code but it shows wrong output. The problem is it replaces every "O" in the string. I'm not familiar with regex and don't know what is the right regex for my problem. TIA.

> Here's my code:

```
    import re
    tagged_text = st.tag(per_word(input_file))
    string_type = "\n".join(" ".join(line) for line in tagged_text)

    for line in string_type:
        output_file.write (re.sub('O$', 'NONE', line))
```

> Sample Input:

```
Tropical O
    Storm O
    Jolina O
    affects O
    2,000 O
    people O
    MANILA LOCATION
    , O
    Philippines LOCATION
    – O
    Initial O
    reports O
    from O
    the O
```

> OUTPUT:

```
Tropical NONE
Storm NONE
Jolina NONE
affects NONE
2,000 NONE
people NONE
MANILA LNONECATINONEN
, NONE
Philippines LNONECATINONEN
– NONE
Initial NONE
reports NONE
from NONE
the NONE
```

Comment: What is `string_type`? It seems you are looping through a string, which will check character by character.

Comment: @Psidom I converted  the tagged_text(tuples) into a string(string_type) then read line by line.

Comment: At what instance it is failing . for e.g., i tried like 
`line = 'TrOpical O'
re.sub('O$','NONE',line)`

'TrOpical NONE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through `string_type`, use `re.sub` directly on the string should work:

```
s = """Tropical O
    Storm O
    Jolina O
    affects O
    2,000 O
    people O
    MANILA LOCATION
    , O
    Philippines LOCATION
    – O
    Initial O
    reports O
    from O
    the O"""

import re
print(re.sub(r"\bO(?=\n|$)", "NONE", s))
```

gives:

```
Tropical NONE
    Storm NONE
    Jolina NONE
    affects NONE
    2,000 NONE
    people NONE
    MANILA LOCATION
    , NONE
    Philippines LOCATION
    – NONE
    Initial NONE
    reports NONE
    from NONE
    the NONE
```

Here `\bO(?=\n|$)` matches a single letter `O` followed by either a new line character `\n` or the end of line `$`.